# Allow selected IAM users to switch role

Tags: amazon-iam

I have two AWS accounts(`Account A & B`). I want to allow few IAM users of `Account B` to access resources of `Account A` via `AWS IAM` roles.

I have created the role and it works fine. However, I see that any IAM user who gets hold of the role name is able to switch roles and access the resources.

Is there a way to allow only specific users of Account B to be able to switch to the role?

The trust policy statement is as follows-

```
 {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account-B:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the users who should be restricted to assume the role to a group. Then you can attach IAM policy to the IAM group with an explicit Deny.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::Account_A_ID:role/Rolename"
  }
}
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html#tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html#tutorial_cross-account-with-roles-2